# Xcode cannot find pods library

Tags: xcode, cocoa, linker, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods for my dependency management but apparently XCode cannot seem to find my libPods library although I've added it in the Link Binary With Libraries. Here's more info

[image]

Here is how my binaries look

[image]

Is there anything else I'm missing or some wrong configuration?

P.S.: I've tried cleaning, rebuilding and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your "Library Search Path" build setting. The `libPods.a` file will need to be in one of those search paths.

Comment: Yeah that was the missing link but shouldn't CocoaPods do this for me?

Comment: I haven't used CocoaPods so I'm not sure. Are you opening the special workspace CocoaPods creates, or the usual Xcode project?

Comment: Yeah I am. It seems I would need to play around more with cocoapods to be comfortable with it.